# Highlight all files open in buffer in NERDTree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

Is it possible to get a list of all files in the buffer? And if so can we highlight all of them in NERDTree?

Comment: Like `:ls` (for listing open buffers)?

Comment: `:ls` works! I guess what's needed is a NERDTree syntax file that highlights lines matching the output of `:ls` on everytime the buffer changes?

Comment: This is not how syntax files work.  You could however post a feature request to the [official channel](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues).

Comment: Looks like it was requested (two years ago) [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/300)